# Learning J2EE after developing in ASP.NET WF and MVC

Tags: asp.net, jakarta-ee

I've been developing in ASP.NET for 1,5 years. (I used first Web Forms for a year and when I get a new project I decided to learn MVC) Now I am about changing job where they want me to develop in J2EE or SpringMVC. How long does it take to get practice in those (not to get pro just to reach a level to make good quality software)? I think that those web frameworks are very similar to the web frameworks of .NET I used.

Am I think right? Is there somebody who have changed from .NET to Java (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of it as there are two main things you need to understand in order to build good quality software:

- The general principles of the area you're working in
- The specific details of the technology you're using at the time.

In the web-space, the principles of ASP.net and the concept of MVC is pretty similar to the concept of the SpringMVC.  There are loads of Model-View-* type frameworks, which basically have the same concepts behind them.

You'll have the same set of concerns building an application in Java as you did in ASP.NET - Separate business logic from presentation, connect to a database, appropriate level of logging, security, error management, authentication, etc. etc.

The concepts you learned using ASP.NET you'll be able to re-use in the Java space.

The specifics of how you utilise them will be different (although often, surprisingly similar - compare nunit with junit, Hibernate with nHibernate).  It'll take a little while to get to grips with how SpringMVC works and how it's configured, with how to build and deploy a Java project, with the particular structure of the libraries.

But in the end it's the same principles.

Also, particularly in the web space, all of the HTML, CSS, javascript, browser compatibility, user experience is identical.  How you include that stuff in your project varies a little, but the actual markup that gets sent to the browser, and the challenges in making it right are exactly the same.

Doing something new like this will help too, because you'll see where the similarities are, and where the differences are.  It might help highlight *why* they're similar.

It would be really good if you got on a project with some experienced Java people on it.  They'll have the basics down and be able to structure it so that most of the big risks are managed, so you can get to grips with the technologies and differences to start off with.

Most really good developers can develop in several languages.  I recommend you add Java to your list.